# Camel PollEnrich rejecting "file location" is not started, but in state: Stopped

Tags: apache-camel

Apologies for my English, it's very late and I'm very tired and not making much sense

I have about 4 poll-enriches looking at file locations each on Quartz cron-jobs in Camel

I poll about 4 times at 10 seconds intervals

```
// portFolioHoldingsCron = 0/10+*+*+?+*+* )
// the first cron is just evaluates quartz://holdingsRefreshTimer?portfolioHoldingsCron=0/10+*+*+?+*+*
```

The pollEnrich to

```
        from( bridge.components().quartz( "holdingsRefreshTimer", portfolioHoldingsCron ) )
        .log( "PORTFOLIO HOLDINGS TIMER EVENT")
        .pollEnrich( portfolioHoldingsCamelFromUrl, portfolioPollTimeout )
        .choice()
            .when(  body().isNull() )
            .log( "No Firm data retreived from " + portfolioFirmsCamelFromUrl )
            // END
        .otherwise()
                .process( new Processor() {
                    @Override
                    public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {

                    }
                })
        .log("PORTFOLIO HOLDINGS RECEIVED AND PROCESSING")
        .unmarshal()
        .bindy(BindyType.Csv, Holding.class)
        .log("Holdings unmarshalled")
```

After some arbitrary time (e.g. 30 seconds) the routes suddenly all break with (there is a lot of these messages on different routes)

I never told them to stop or to shut-down. I don't know why this is happening, it's very confusing

The exception I get is:

```
org.quartz.JobExecutionException: java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: PollingConsumer on Endpoint[file://inbox/holding?noop=true] is not started, but in state: Stopped [See nested exception: java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: PollingConsumer on Endpoint[file://inbox/holding?noop=true] is not started, but in state: Stopped]
at org.apache.camel.component.quartz.QuartzEndpoint.onJobExecute(QuartzEndpoint.java:117)
at org.apache.camel.component.quartz.CamelJob.execute(CamelJob.java:54)
at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:216)
at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:549)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: PollingConsumer on Endpoint[file://portfolio-inbox/holding?noop=true] is not started, but in state: Stopped
at org.apache.camel.impl.EventDrivenPollingConsumer.receive(EventDrivenPollingConsumer.java:84)
at org.apache.camel.processor.PollEnricher.process(PollEnricher.java:172)
at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorConverterHelper$ProcessorToAsyncProcessorBridge.process(AsyncProcessorConverterHelper.java:61)
at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:73)
at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.processNext(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:99)
at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:90)
at org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor.process(InstrumentationProcessor.java:73)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that using a quartz on a timer of 10 seconds or less makes these pollEnrich problems occur

When I set the time as 15 seconds and longer the problems ended

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use seda as a workaround;

from(quartz:...)
.to("seda:next");

from("seda:next")
.pollEnrich()
...

Comment: it affected every route in camel, not just the one I was looking at, I think the key is not to set the delay between quartz timings too small because camel appears to break under certain conditions